# How to Auto Redirect Using WP-Geolocation-js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, geolocation, geo

Hello friends when i use wp-geolocation pluggin short code it is accuratly showing my location 
but i need little more than this

iam trying to auto redirect url based on location like following

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://[mmjs-city].gumpul.com/"
//-->
</script>
```

but it does not redirecting

but when i use "[mmjs-city]" short code it is showing my city namje correctly please show me a sollution

http://www.wp-geolocation.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var url= "http://"+geoip_city()+".gumpul.com/";
window.location = url;

</script>
```